# TE to check two events coinciding or delayed

Tags: specman

I have two events @A and @B. I want to check that at occurrence of @A, @B is either emitted at the same time or some cycles later.

```
expect my_check is ((@A and @B) or (@A => {[0..N]; @B}))@clk exec { 
  message(NONE, "my_check");
};
```

However, I can see (from the message) that the TE succeeds every clock cycle from the start of the simulation. This is puzzling, as neither A nor B occur in that timeframe. Any ideas what's wrong? Is it forbidden to mix boolean and temporal yield operator?

Answer (score 2):

What you see here is a vacuous pass. The first sub expression is FALSE, and evaluation advances to the next sub expression. That second sub expression evaluates to TRUE since the prerequisite @A does *not* occur (in which case the implication couldn't care less about the RHS expression). Hence, the OR is satisfied and the exec block is activated.

Answer (score 1):

After some experimenting I found:

```
 expect my_check is @A => ({[..N-1];@B} or detach({@B; ~[..1]}))@clk
```

Note that this still requires a 2nd expect statement to check for spurious B events.