# specman - expect event after several cycles

Tags: monitor, verification, specman

I have the following events:

```
   event rstn_release_e            is rise (smp.port_rstn$)              @sim;
   event d_dis_feedback_to_spot_e is rise (smp.port_d_dis_feedback$)   @sim;
   event osc_clk_e                 is rise (smp.port_osc_clk$)           @sim;
```

I have to verify that when r`stn_release_e` event occurs the event `d_dis_feedback_to_spot_e` occurs after 0-2 cycles of oscillator clock (`osc_clk_e`).

I use the following:

```
expect @rstn_release_e => {[..2]*@osc_clk_e ; @d_dis_feedback_to_spot_e};
```

The simulation fails because for some reason the above expect "works" according simulation clock instead of oscillator clock

Comment: Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/q/32822270/1353186

Answer (score 1):

seems that you did not define the sampling event for the expect

```
expect @rstn_release_e => {[..2] ; @d_dis_feedback_to_spot_e} @osc_clk_e;
```